# Reduce area to scan in Android

Tags: android, camera, barcode, zbar

Is it possible to reduce the area to scan in the camera?

I have multiple barcodes next to each other and I need a way to differentiate them.

I'm using ZBar.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to crop the image that you will be getting in previewCallback and then pass it to zBar. Meanwhile you can also show some differentiation of area being scanned on surface by using overlay.